# How do I get my function to return to a specific point in my program in an if statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want my function to work so that if someone enters more grades than the 20 allowed it returns to another point, whether in the function or out of it, so that the user has the option to try again. What do I need to change, I know return can't be the answer as it just exists the function and goes to the next line after the function call. This is for homework, and I'm honestly not sure this is even necessary, I just want it to be clean and handle user errors.

```
void gradeTaker()
{
    cout << "You may input up to 20 grades. \n";
    cout << "First enter the number of grades you have: \n";
    cin >> gradeCounted;
    if (gradeCounted > arraySize)
    {
        cout << "You entered a number of grades greater than 20, try again \n";
        return;
    }
}
```

The current result of my code is it exits the function and continues to the following line. I don't know the code necessary for what I want.

Comment: Try using a loop.

Comment: The desired result that you've described: there's nothing like that, whatsoever, in C++. You must figure out how to use the existing C++ facilities that govern the program's logical execution flow: `if`, `for`, `do`, `while`, function calls, `return`, the ternary operator, and thrown exceptions (as well as the`g*` word), in order to achieve your desired results.

Comment: I removed the question regarding ctrl-k. You can visit “meta” to ask those questions (you’ll find the link in the SE logo menu on the far right of the top bar). Also, you managed to format your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I appreciate your time in helping me to learn. I was only able to use ctrl+k on the review page, I'll check out the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use while loop to take the input with the condition:

```cpp
void gradeTaker() {
    cout << "You may input up to 20 grades. \n";
    cout << "First enter the number of grades you have: \n";
    cin >> gradeCounted;
    while (gradeCounted > arraySize) {
        cout << "You entered a number of grades greater than 20, try again \n";
        cin >> gradeCounted;
    }
    // do whatever with gradeCount
}
```

Also do a while loop, label with goto statement, and some other logic to achieve.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate your time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am glad It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function 'gradeTaker()' from inside itself instead of 'return'